# Help proving limits don't exist.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am not asking about any specific limits. For some reason rigorously proving a limit does not exist using an epsilon delta proof gives me a lot of trouble. Typically my book does this by negating the definition of a limit. Deciding on what to use as the $/epsilon$ is generally tricky for me. Is there a general strategy for this? Could you explain to me your thought process when you prove that one does not exist? Also these are single variable calculus type of limits.

Comment: what does DNE stand for?

Comment: One strategy (for limits at a finite point) would be to compute the limit on the left and the limit on the right and show that they are not equal.

Comment: If you want to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow P} f(x)$ doesn't exist you could also try to find a sequence converging to $P$ that doesn't have a limit or two different sequences converging to $P$ that have different limits.

Comment: Usually existence of limits is proven by epsilon delta. Non existence is proven by showing that value approaches different values when limit point is approached from different directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit does not exist if there is a lack of continuity in the neighbourhood about the value of interest.

Most limits DNE when 
$$\lim_{x\to a^−}f(x)\neq \lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$$, This typically occurs in piecewise or step functions.
A common misunderstanding is that limits DNE when there is a point discontinuity in rational functions. On the contrary, the limit exists perfectly at the point of discontinuity

One imporant way that limits don’t exist is that they go off to infinity.
For example,

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}=\infty$$

***One general strategy is to try solving $|f(x) − L| <\epsilon$  for $x$. Once you know what values of x
will work, you choose $δ$ so that the interval $(a − \delta, a + \delta)$ sits inside the set of solutions.***

**$l$ is not the limit if there exist an$\epsilon >0$ such that no choice of $\delta >0$ ensures $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$  whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$.**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show that limx→Pf(x) doesn't exist you could also try to find a sequence converging to P that doesn't have a limit or two different sequences converging to P that have different limits.
An example of this is $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \cos(\frac{1}{x}) $$ You can show that this limit doesn't exist considering the sequences $ (\frac{1}{2n \pi})_n$ and $(\frac{1}{(2n+1) \pi })_n$ , infact their limits are
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \cos(2n \pi) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1 = 1 $$
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \cos(2n \pi + \pi) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} -1 = -1 $$ 
You can conclude that $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \cos(\frac{1}{x}) $ doesn't exists.